# Extract drive letter from "set /p P=" in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to extract the drive letter from "set /P P=" variable, containing the path to a folder.

```
    set /P P=
    echo %~dP
```

I have read the help and also tried many variants using % and %% but I can't understand why it is not working.

When I try...

```
    echo %~d1
```

it works perfectly, but using command line parameters is not an option.

I'm not stupid, just a novice.

Comment: FYI %~ notation only works for the numeric variables a batch receives to represent itself and its arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samples and general usage in `set /?`

```
echo %p:~0,1%
```

From variable %p%, from first position (0 index based), take one character. To include the colon (two characters)

```
echo %p:~0,2%
```

If you prefer the sintax in your question, then a `for` command can be used

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%p%") do echo %%~da
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's it. Tried second variant, but didn't overcome ("%p%") part, used something like ('%%p') and (%p%) instead, got errors or nothing.